# xml to sql - need a few more data from the xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

while having this xml data:

```
    <machine>ZSK40-2</machine>
<date>2013/08/28</date>
<hour>12:37</hour>
<CollectedData>
  <variable>
    <Name>PRODUCT</Name>
    <Value>FILLER 580</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>LOT_NUMBER</Name>
    <Value>CG 00063 0</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SHIFT_SUPERVISOR</Name>
    <Value> covaliu l</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KGH_ALL_SET</Name>
    <Value>90</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KGH_ALL_REAL</Name>
    <Value>133.183883666992</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KGH_F1_SET</Name>
    <Value>90</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KGH_F1_REAL</Name>
    <Value>133.183883666992</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>K_F1</Name>
    <Value>33</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SCREW_RPM_SET</Name>
    <Value>400</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SCREW_RPM_REAL</Name>
    <Value>399.452606201172</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>TORQUE</Name>
    <Value>19.6692142486572</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>CURRENT</Name>
    <Value>71.0029983520508</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KW_KG</Name>
    <Value>0.0553370267152786</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>KW</Name>
    <Value>7.36999988555908</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>MELT_PRESSURE</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>MELT_TEMPERATURE</Name>
    <Value>140</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV1</Name>
    <Value>141</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP1</Name>
    <Value>140</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV2</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP2</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV3</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP3</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV4</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP4</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV5</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP5</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV6</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP6</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV7</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP7</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV8</Name>
    <Value>154</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP8</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV9</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP9</Name>
    <Value>150</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV10</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP10</Name>
    <Value>160</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>PV11</Name>
    <Value>180</Value>
  </variable>
  <variable>
    <Name>SP11</Name>
    <Value>180</Value>
  </variable>
</CollectedData>
```

and with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE #ZSK70(
 Name varchar(25) ,
 Value varchar(30) );


INSERT INTO #ZSK70 (Name, Value) 
SELECT X.variable.query('Name').value('.', 'varchar(25)'),
       X.variable.query('Value').value('.', 'varchar(30)')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
     BULK 'C:\20130828_1237_ZSK40-2.xml',
     SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
     ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('CollectedData/variable') AS X(variable);

select * from #ZSK70 
drop table #ZSK70
```

i get some data from the xml.
How can i get also the machine and date + time in a datetime row. 
thanks in advance for the help! 
Will keep an eye here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT X.variable.query('Name').value('.', 'varchar(25)'),
   X.variable.query('Value').value('.', 'varchar(30)'),
   X2.variable.query('machine').value('.','varchar(30)'),
   X2.variable.query('date').value('.','datetime')
FROM ( 
SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(
 BULK 'C:\20130828_1237_ZSK40-2.xml',
 SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)
 ) AS T(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('CollectedData/variable') AS X(variable)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/') AS X2(variable);
```

p.s. I think the reason for the downvotes on your question is that you left the OpenRowset in your query with a reference to an external file.  This makes it a bit of a pain to work with the example you provided.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. will keep in mind what you told me. also your solution worked like a charm. I apreciate your time for me. Have a nice day.